# Should I encrypt memorable-word?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, two-step-verification

We're using a two-step authentication on a web-app, which consist of:

1- Username/password
2- [Memorable-word](https://ask.barclayswealth.com/help/international/wealth-online/login/memorable-word)

The password is being hashed then stored, where the memorable-word is stored as it is, obviously, it is as important as the password, do you recommend to encrypt it then store it or leave it as it is?

Comment: So how is the memorable word different from a second password? I cannot see an advantage in requiring a second password, it is safer if the user invests this effort in choosing a stronger first password.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Strong password is a must, however, in case the user's password got exposed, the memorable-word will be the savior. It is not a second factor but a second step, like a gate and a door irl.